# Is it possible to add a timer to a button?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button that performs an action, is it possible to create a timer so the button can only be used every 6 hours or so?

Would need to be for each specific user, so if one user presses the button, it won't affect another user's cooldown or ability to press it.

Here's the form

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="addgold.php">
<input type="submit" name="Add gold" value="Work" onclick="addgold()" />
</form>
```

And here's the action that the button performs if it is needed

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['userlogin'])){
$username = $_SESSION['userlogin'];
$sql = "SELECT stats.id, stats.gold, users.id, users.username FROM stats, users WHERE users.username     = '$username' AND stats.id = users.id";
$retval = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Gold :{$row['gold']}  <br> ".

     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($retval); 
$result = $row[0]; 


echo "<a href=\"main.php\">Back to main page</a>";
}else{
?>

<?php
echo "fail";
}
?>
```

I found a similar answer to this in another Stackoverflow question (this site has everything) that said it can only be done in javascript, which is fine besides I haven't a clue about javascript!
There was some code he/she put with it

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
document.forms['form_name'].submit();
}, 1000);
```

But where do I put that? into my php page? if so, where?

Comment: It is not JAVA but it is a Javascript. Huge difference.

Comment: You need to save the user and the last time he clicked the button ( preferrably in a database ).

Comment: @tttpapi I know sorry, edited!

Comment: @DOCASAREL Yeah that makes sense, can you point me in the right direction to learn the code? I can't find anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really important how you want the button will work.

1) **Is it only for registered users**

Save it to database. And then just check the DB time difference.

2) **For everyone**

If it does not have to be 100 % accurate you can use a session or you can also save the information to DB and then check the difference.

Comment: Saving it through the database seems the best way :) I'll get on it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your app has authentication in place, which identifies each user uniquely, you can create a table in your DB (or add a column to your users table) which stores  the last time a user has pressed the button as a DATETIME type.

Then all you have to do when the page is requested is calculate the difference between the current time and the one stored in your DB. Using mysql:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),last_pressed)) AS time_passed FROM my_table
```

If the difference is less than 6 hours you simply remove or disable the button. Do note that removing the button is not enough and you have to block the action on the server side as well, because a seasoned user can send the request via the browser's URL bar or using curl without using the button.

If you don't have proper session authentication, you can resort to @ploutch's solution, and save the IP address instead of the user ID. This is not perfect because the headers sent to the server can be tampered with by the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your limiter in javascript, it will be done client-side, which means if a user knows about programming, he'll easily be able to go around that protection.

If you really want to enforce a time limit between clicks, it should be done server-side, but that means that the server must be able to recognize clients. What is generally done is using the IP address (even if it's not perfect), which you can get by checking the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compel observance of  time limit between clicks surely you would need to use `$_SESSION[]` in php(server side) for this purpose and save the information to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Try `setTimeout` function in javascript

```
<input type="button" value="click" id="click" onclick="foo(this);"/>​
```

in javascript

```
function foo(obj) {
    obj.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        obj.disabled = false;
    }, 2000);
}​
```